# form tag in html not posting/hitting website

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

so im trying to create a link shortener for me and my friend
to use on our small service center
but im having a small problem.
i set up an express server to get this done, whilst creating a fileuploader
which i used postman to test.
both work fine, but this is where im getting the problem.
whenever i use the snippet below to try and send data to the 'api'
it doesnt even post/touch the website *yes i debugged to see if it touched*
its only when i use form post/get method that the code doesnt work

HTML code snippet

```html
 <form method="POST" action="/shorten" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                <label for="fUrl" class="sronly">URL</label>
                <input class="input"
                    required
                    placeholder="URL"
                    type="url"
                    name="fUrl"
                    id="fUrl"
                />
    <button type="submit">Shrink This!</button>
    </form>
```

ive tried many things, i dont know if its because im rendering it with EJS or what
i tested it on its own with an HTML file but to no avail
if theres anything in this post i missed to go over let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of browsers being a tad too fast/slow

fix is here

```js
// thanks to Vikasdeep Singh for this oddly specific url regex test
function isValidURL(string) {
    var res = string.match(/(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g);
    return (res !== null)
};

var el = document.getElementById("yourButtonID");
el.addEventListener("click", avoidNSErrorWithFirefox, false); //Firefox

function avoidNSErrorWithFirefox() {
    ElementInterval = setInterval(function() {
        var url = document.getElementById("inputURL").value; // input tag
        if (isValidURL(url)) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "https://your-url.com/shorten", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
                "url": url
            }));
        }
        clearInterval(ElementInterval);
    }, 0);
};
```

works like a charm on all browsers ive tested

> edge chrome opera firefox

Hopefully me and my friends fix saves you some trouble with form / express problems!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is some issue with mapping between client and server. Try changing **action** value to the your API endpoint.

```
 <form method="POST" action="http://myserver.com/shorten" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <label for="fUrl" class="sronly">URL</label>
            <input class="input"
                required
                placeholder="URL"
                type="url"
                name="fUrl"
                id="fUrl"
            />
<button type="submit">Shrink This!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Sadly ive also tried this aswell, i dont know if its an issue on localhost but it shouldnt be